# Why isn't Tobi blind yet?

Tags: naruto

There is a Naruto character named Tobi who maintains his eyesight though his special ability *should* have caused a great amount of macular degeneration. The following includes extensive spoilers.

> By my math, Tobi possesses his Mangekyo for quite some years. It *is* his Mangekyo, he stated it himself. So in that case, how come he hadn't gone blind yet? Itachi went almost completely blind in under 10 years. Sasuke got half blind in less than 1 year (because he abused it freely).

So how come Tobi hasn't gone blind? As far as I can figure:

> He obviously replaced his other eye, but it was kept behind his one-eyed mask for a long period of time, he didn't use it for vision.

Comment: Very good point. I know he loses the eye behind his mask using Izanagi when fighting Konan but it never occurred to me that he should be blind in his original eye. Wonder if Hashirama's cells have anything to do with that since they have healing properties?

Comment: Don't you think this question carries major spoilers? :S

Comment: @Alenanno: Spoilers only count if they are over the scope of the title. Though I'm very very tempted to add a spoiler warning to the title as well.

Comment: I agree with @Alenanno. You should use the spoiler tag.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Come to chat. :P

Comment: I agree with the above comments. Although it is a legitimate question and it should be allowed, it could be a major spoiler for someone just starting to watch or read naruto... There should be some way to hide this from these people...

Comment: Ehhhhh, why don't you ask him yourself, he's besides you for almost a year now.

Comment: @Sid: You don't get it, *I* already know the answer, I want to give others a chance too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer contains lots of spoilers so I might as well make one block, edit if you will

> When Madara rescued Obito from the collapsed cave he used Hashirama
>  Senju's living clone to heal Obito's crushed body. Not only did this
>  heal Obito's body but it also gave him access to Hashirama Senju's
>  abilities, the wood release ability, as seen when he defeated the
>  ninjas who wanted to steal Rin's body.
>  Now Hashirama Senju had unique medical ninjutsu which healed himself without forming any
>  seals whatsoever. So if Obito gained access to the wood release ninjutsu he may also gained 
>  this medical ninjutsu, which in turn healed his eye throughout the years.

Comment: I'm actually not sure if a medical ninjutsu of any kind can heal a dying Mangekyo. It was said that only eye replacement would work. Though I guess it's possible.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha
It is Hashirama's cells after all, whom none other than Uchiha Madara acknowledged as the greatest medical ninja, so it is definitely believable.

Comment: @Happy then what would be the situation in Kakashi's case?

Answer (score 1):

When Tobi is not yet revealed to be

> Obito Uchiha

, it's shown that he's collecting Sharingan-Eyes. So it would be logical, that he took two of these eyes to not go blind.

> Remeber: Tobi was actually angered when he saw that Danzo sealed the Sharingan of Shisui, because he couldn't use it anymore.

Comment: Then how does his current eye still share the same powers as Kakashi?  That part wouldn't make sense if he had transplanted a different eye, right?

Comment: @MCeley: Didn't think about that. Maybe it's because Kakashi carries the DNA of Obito in his eye? Don't know.

Comment: No. It was seen that when you replace eyes, the power of it changes. Tobi still has his original power in his right eye, so it's extremely likely it's still the original.